# JSONpath, only return result if other element has a value

Tags: jsonpath

I am looking for the JSONpath expression to extract elements in an array only if it contains another element.

The following expression returns all elements;

```
$.differ.element[*]['id','alias']
```

This is the JSON file:

```
{
    "differ": {
        "element": [
            {
                "id": "Address",
                "alias": [
                    "Information about address"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "Address.extension",
                "path": "Address.extension"

            },
            {
                "id": "Address.extension:official",
                "path": "Address.extension",
                "alias": [
                    "Mark address"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
[
    "Address",
    [
        "Information about address"
    ],
    "Address.extension",
    "Address.extension:official",
    [
        "Mark address"
    ]
]
```

I would like to omit the 'Address.extension' element as it does not have an alias. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

`$.differ.element[?(@.alias)]`

will get output like this :

```
[
    {
        "id":"Address",
        "alias":[
            "Information about address"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":"Address.extension:official",
        "path":"Address.extension",
        "alias":[
            "Mark address"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Ajinkya, this works, but it also gives me the path element:
"path": "Address.extension"
Is there anyway to leave this out? In the real JSON there are many more elements.